# Native plugins with phonegap build

Tags: cordova

I've been struggling with that for days and couldn't find a solution. I Know how to use phonegap plugins with it,but how do I use my own  Java file?

Comment: Private plugins aren't supported by PG Build, you have to contribute your plugin as a public plugin if you want it available in Build. See the [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_contributing_plugins.md.html#Contributing%20Plugins).

Comment: @Marcin PG Build is the cloud build, isn't it? I guess this doesn't apply to plain Cordova apps.